# getting ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Tags: python, integer-division

I had written a simple pascal triangle code in python but I am getting a error

```
def factorial(n):
    c=1
    re=1
    for c in range(n):
        re = re * c;
    return(re)

print "Enter how many rows of pascal triangle u want to show \n"
n=input();
i=1
c=1
for i in range(n):
    for c in range(n-i-1):
        print ""
        for c in range(i):
            a = factorial(i);
            b = factorial(c);
            d = factorial(i-c);
            z = (a/(b*d));
            print "%d" % z
            print "\n"
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tanmaya/workspace/abc/a.py", line 19, in <module>
    z = (a/(b*d));
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: **integer division or modulo by zero** means `b*d` resulted in zero

Comment: Please choose a better title for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `factorial()` function returns 0 for any input because of how you defined your range.

The range builtin starts at 0 unless otherwise defined so:

```
for c in range(n):
    re = re * c  # no semicolons in Python
```

is doing:

```
re = re * 0
```

on the first iteration so for all subsequent iterations:

```
re = 0 * c
```

will always be 0

Start your range at 1 like so

```
for c in range(1, n):
    re *= c  # The *= operator is short hand for a = a * b
```

you can see this more explicityly:

```
>>> print(list(range(5)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(list(range(1,5)))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

or instead of rolling your own function use the one that comes with Python:

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> factorial(3)
6
```

Upon closer reading of your code it seems you tried to circumvent this by setting `c = 1` outside your `for` loop. This is not going to work because the variables you declared outside the loop are being reassigned inside it.

Comment: @TanuTanmay Well I'm not familiar with Pascal triangles so you'll have to open a new question and post your new problem there.

Answer (score 4):

**ZeroDivisionError** means that you were trying to divide or modulo,  a number `n` with 0.
in your case, `z = (a/(b*d))` resulted in `z = (a/0)`

Also, as @theB pointed out, your `factorial` function is incorrect.

Try fixing those.

Also, you don't really need `;` in your code. It's usually the case we put `;` when we want to make the code one liner.

Comment: May also want to point out that the factorial function is not producing anything close to a correct result.

Comment: @theB the code is such a mess, I didn't bother running it. Thanks for noting that.

Comment: It just seemed weird, since `x! != 0`