# ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero when using ImageDataGenerator and .flow_from_directory

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am trying to run the code https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb which uses VGG16. My data set is from https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data. I have three folders test, train, validate in a folder called sample. I use the non used images in the train folder and store it in validate.

I looked at [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379687/getting-zerodivisionerror-integer-division-or-modulo-by-zero), [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836955/zerodivisionerror-integer-division-or-modulo-by-zero), or [Solution 3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10129) for the error **ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero** , however I cant seem to address the problem I am facing. The error occurs at  `features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch`.

```
  import keras
    keras.__version__
    from keras.applications import VGG16

    conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                      include_top=False,
                      input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

    conv_base.summary()
    import os
    import numpy as np
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    base_dir = 'C:\\Users\\K\\Documents\\Code\\sample'
    test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')
    train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
    validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')


    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    batch_size = 20

    def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
        features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512))
        labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
        generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='binary')
        i = 0
        for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
            features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
            features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
            labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
            i += 1
            if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
                # Note that since generators yield data indefinitely in a loop,
                # we must `break` after every image has been seen once.
                break

        return features, labels

    train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000)
    validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, 1000)
    test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 1000)
```

Comment: It is clear that datagen and generator is empty as it does not appear as I step through the code. Therefore I think the error is a result of the folder setup, but I still not such how to address. Please correct me if I am wrong as I am a newbie to python.

Comment: base_dir needs to point to the folder where you previously (in the previous notebook https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.2-using-convnets-with-small-datasets.ipynb) extracted the images and divided them into train, validation and test folders. I think you are pointing to the wrong folder, or haven't extracted the images as specified before.